# What is the best way to get values from the currently selected row in a WPF datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, .net-core, datagrid

We have recently decided to recreate our Winforms app in WPF. In Winforms I get the values of the current row like so:

`Dim supplier As String = tbl_outstandingpos.CurrentRow.Cells("Supplier").Value`

In WPF the best way I could find so far is

```
DataRowView row = dataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
MessageBox.Show(row.Row.ItemArray[1].ToString());
```

Which doesn't work for me as I don't want to get the column by index but by name.

I have read a lot about MVVM, I still don't see that giving the results I am looking for.

I want the user to select a row, then there are labels/textblocks that are filled with the values from that row(Some of which are in hidden columns in the DataGrid)

I am using C# for the new app, we used VB for the winforms one.

Comment: You can typecast the dataGrid.SelectedItem to bind type as `(<<YourType>>dataGrid.SelectedItem). With that change, you can access the properties of object directly.`

Comment: Set a binding on the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` to bind it to the view model which should expose a property e.g., `SelectedRow` of the same type as the items of the data grid's `ItemsSource`. Now bind the `Label` and `TextBlock` controls to the `SelectedRow` property (the data item) of the view model. If you would show more code like your view model items source and the relevant view controls I will provide an example.

Comment: @BionicCode I don't have a viewmodel :(. I have a datatable that is filled using a SQL query and adapter. Then I set the datagrid's item source to the datatable's defaultview

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` is a `DataTable` the `SelectedItem` will be an `DataRowView` instance. You can access the selected row by column name by using the appropriate indexer property:

**C#**

```
// Get the value of the selected row's 'LastName' column
var columnValue = (this.MyDataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView)["LastName"];
this.MyTextBlock.Text = columnValue;
```

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable}" />

<!-- A TextBlock to display the content of the selected rows 'LastName'  column -->
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" 
           Text="{Binding ElementName=DataGrid, Path=SelectedItem[LastName]}"/>
```

You may consider to add a dedicated `SelectedRow` property of type `DataRowView` to your view model instead of having your controls bind directly to the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am surprised that something like this is more complicated in WPF than in WinForms. Will the DataTable binding work if my DT is created at runtime?

Comment: How is this more complicated? If you compare the C# versions it's the same. The XAML adds extra flexibility and extensibility which is missing in WinForms which doesn't have a markup language to describe the view at all.

Comment: I didn't have to google or ask here to find out how to do it in WinForms. I type mytablename then visual studio hints currentrow then cells I type the name of the one I want. I get an error saying value of type datagridviewtextboxcell can not be converted to label. I add Value on the end and done it works.

Comment: If you go the the XAML way you'd know how to handle binding on an `ItemsControl` and that the property `Selector.SelectedItem` is a 'generic' one (of type `object`), so there is no chance for Intellisense to show you the underlying type. If you'd have been going all XAML, you might have chosen a different approach to populate the `DataGrid`. Because you went the C# way you happen to chose the most complicated and unintuitive way to populate the view. The `DataGrid` is very complex because it is very flexible and customizable.

Comment: I would say the most obvious way or intuitive way when used to XAML would be to bind the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to a collection of data models in your view model. You would then create or instantiate those data models from your result data of your database query. Preferably you would already use some ORM (data to object mapping) and maybe bind to those POCO objects directly. This way your selected item is simply the current instance of the data model. This model instance would also be the `DataContext` of your `DataTemplate`.

Comment: If setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to `True` columns are generated having the property name as column name and header. So no worry about column templating. Very straight forward. You would never have to worry about how the `DataGrid` internally handels the rather unconventional data source of a `DataTable` and that `DataRow` elements are interacted with using their view representation (`DataRowView`).

Comment: I'd prefer to do it the XAML way. I am trying to learn it as I go, but I have only been given 2 weeks to transfer our WinForms, VB, .net framework Application into a WPF, C#, .net core one. It seems like trying to get setup with ViewModels and ORMs will delay that. Although I know it will be better in the long run.